# Delusional? delusions of grandeur? paranoid? Help!

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms, terminology

How can I describe someone who thinks I have special connections with people such as the government, state, etc?

I am hoping for a special descriptive word for someone who keeps telling me to send them a contact person that they can call... P.S. I don't have special connections.
Thank You!!

Comment: A person with delusions of grandeur thinks _they_ are someone special, not somebody else.

Comment: *mistaken*.....

Answer (score 2):

Tell that person he/she is "misinformed".  That is not so negative and judgmental as "delusional" or "paranoid".

Comment: And the misinformation likely stems from *wishful thinking*.

Comment: Even if someone actually is delusional or paranoid, telling them so probably isn't useful.

Answer (score 0):

One relevant idiom is **suck-up**

> [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=suck-up)
> *suck-up*
> Someone who will kiss up to someone and literally do anything for them in order to get something from that person.
> John: *Hi Mr. kennington, I would love to shine your shoes or do a favor for you. Btw, I need to get my grade up in your class.*
>
> Mr.Kennington: *stop being a suck-up*

The use of *literally* in this definition is misleading and inappropriate, but the definition otherwise conveys the feeling of a person who may suck up (=fawn on) someone to whom they (perhaps mistakenly) attribute power and influence.